# How safe is the quicken encryption of files?

Tags: security, encryption, quicken

Quicken has a password-protection option where you type in a password and your file is encrypted. How good is this encryption and how does it depend on the length or complexity of my password?

A google search reveals a lot of "quicken password recovery" programs, like [this one](http://lastbit.com/quicken/default.asp), which make me feel like the password is just for keeping the really dumb criminals away, not the ones with large computers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SANS did a study and rated it very low.  http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/casestudies/personal-financial-information-safe-practical-lessons-quicken-password-vulnerabilities_704

Comment: That's a great report! (bad for Quicken, apparently they suck). But, they are analyzing Quicken 2000. Is there a similar report for Quicken >= 2008?

Comment: Search the Quicken site for a link to a tool to have you send your data file to them to remove the password. Fundamentally, any time someone can remove your password, it is inherently breakable by design.  Sorry, I tried to imbed the link, but it keeps breaking.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't rate it as very secure, simply because I don't know how it's being encrypted.

Better bet would be to create a [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) volume and store your Quicken file in there.

Comment: @Idigas: TrueCrypt is an open-source product using known public algorithms and approved by many crypto hackers, including Schneier, the chuck norris of cryptography.

Comment: +1 True Crypt!!! Easy to use, and Cross platform

Comment: Yes, I am doing something similar: re-encrypting the file myself. But, I am still wondering how good quicken is by itself and if anyone has looked at this. It is so popular that someone must have examined it, right?!?

Comment: @Idigas: What sparkly letters? It's a fully open source project using open source algorithms tested by virtually everyone in the Crypto scene. It is **the* cross platform encryption program.

Comment: @jmvidal: Not necessarily. I don't trust Microsoft Word document locking either, specifically because **no one has looked and seen how it's working**. Encryption is a special process that must be done right to avoid any security issues.

Comment: @Josh K - I know it's open source. However, that doesn't mean someone actually invested days/months of it's time to test it throughly. Have you ever trieed reading your own code after a few months. How about somebody elses ? I cannot find it now (figures...), but I recently stumbled upon a very nice article about how much open source code is really tested by ... uhmm, "open sourcers" ... result: not that much. If it's working, most just leave it alone.

Comment: @Idigas: Encryption is taken **very** seriously be professionals and hobbyists alike. I wouldn't say it's out of the possible realm that **many industry qualified professionals** along with a great deal of hobbyists have taken a *very* deep look at the source. Have you ever heard of someone cracking a TrueCrypt volume?